# Reverse of the linked list without changing the links of nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

I tried this code but I got a segmentation fault. How can I fix this error?

```
void rev()
{
    struct node *p,*q;
    p=start;
    q=start;

    int count=0,temp,i,j;

    while(p!=0)
    {
        p=p->next;
        count++;
    }
    for(i=0; i<(count/2); i++)
    {
        p=start;
        for(j=0; j<(count-i); j++)
            p=p->next;

        temp=q->data;
        q->data=p->data;
        p->data=temp;

        q=q->next;
    }
 }
```

Here `p` and `q` are pointers. At first, both are pointing to start.
Then, by using two loops, I swapped the values of first and last node, then second and second last and so on.

Comment: `(count-i)`--> `(count-i-1)`

Comment: Thanks..now the code is working

Answer (score 1):

You have an off-by-one error.  You count `count` elements in the list, then on the first iteration of the `for` list over `i`, you step `p` through  `count - 0` links in the list.  That leaves it NULL, as indeed you just finished determining.  When you then evaluate `p->data` you produce undefined behavior.

Run `i` from 1 to `count / 2` instead of from `0` to `count / 2 - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Ran your `for(i=0; i<(count/2); i++)` on paper.

When you reach the last node in your linked list, both q and p are pointing to the last node;

```
p = p -> next //is NULL so p goes NULL;
```

Your loop is running one iteration more than it should.
so update your inner loop to `count -i - 1`

and when you assign `p -> data = temp` // which NULL -> data = temp, makes no sense

the program crashes and gives a segmentation fault.